# VBA Dictionary - Adding Data

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I am really new to VBA (practicing for 2 weeks now) and I would greatly appreciate your help/advice's regarding the following topic:

I am trying to get to know the dictionary function within vba, but i have a couple of questions:

1. -Is it possible to populate the dictionary with values from a pivot table? For example, you have 2 columns and you put one of them as
   key and the other one as item.
2. How can i use the dictionary as a VlookUp ? I would like to go through it and find the specific item corresponding to this key.

While writing this I feel that the questions are pretty basic but I would really appreciate your help and time and in case it is possible some examples.

Comment: Did you read this: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/? I am pretty sure that you'll find the answer to all your questions in there. The short answers are (1) yes and (2) [using exists](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/#Checking_if_a_Key_Exists).

Comment: Yes, but for example he is just putting the keys manually and I need it to be more automated with dynamic range maybe a for loop ?

Comment: If you have a new question then please post a new question. If you wish to narrow down your question (and be more precise) then please do so in the above post by editing it. Yet, please be **very** specific so we can provide a very specific answer to your question. Note that this site is not a discussion forum but a pure Questions-and-Answers website. No chit-chat. For more information please take the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Okay, thanks for the link